# Should I go with MongoDB auth support or simply bolt on a more application-specific approach?

Tags: node.js, security, mongodb, passwords

New to Node, new to Mongo. Etc Etc...

I'm itching to get started on a project with these two technologies but one of the concerns is security. It seems more terrifying with Node because the server logic is so close to the application, and MongoDB comes with flood-gates open right out of the box.

My question is, am I right in assuming that the only real use for MongoDB's native authentication support (i.e the system.users database) is in the event of needing to screen external connections from outside the server?

So, if I restricted the MongoDB instances to only accept connections through the localhost, would I just leave the authentication to my own application business logic? Or should I be going gun-ho, creating MongoDB documents in system.users for every tom-dick-and-harry that want to 'create an account' with my site?

Is there a middle ground?

For extra kudos, some tips on best practises for password storage in MongoDB would be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I right in assuming that the only real use for MongoDB's native
>   authentication support (i.e the system.users database) is in the event
>   of needing to screen external connections from outside the server?

Yes, essentially.

> should I be going gun-ho, creating MongoDB documents in system.users
>   for every tom-dick-and-harry that want to 'create an account' with my
>   site?

So database applications almost never give each end user a database account, and for good reason. End users don't want nor need a full database account. That's why you have an application - to give the users custom-tailored functionality. Also, generally you want to support a large number of active end users but you only want a small handful of active database connections.  Finally, almost every application has complicated authorization logic that controls which users can read or write which bits of data that the database itself cannot enforce. So typically you can either:

**A)** Have mongo bind to loopback and accept anonymous connections

or

**B)** Create a mongo user that represents your entire application and have the handful of connections from your app server(s) to the database authenticated with these credentials

Both approaches are common and honestly the deployment simplicity of A) frees up some security mind space to focus on more likely vulnerabilities like XSS and so forth.

To summarize:

- loopback without authentication: OK
- loopback with 1 application user: OK
- public IP without authentication: FAIL
- public IP with authentication but no SSL: FAIL
- public IP with authentication and SSL: OK

To store end user password hashes in mongo, [use bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). This is widely documented so I'm not going to reproduce that here for you.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you elaborate slightly on the options you gave? Are you championing A) or telling me to avoid it? Would it not be best to use both options... Bind to 127.0.0.1 but also authenticate on at least one user (which is always used for that particular app's exchanges with the server)? Or are we essentially saying that there is no known way that a scoundrel can worm their way through a port that has been closed to their I.P?

Comment: I updated my answer for you. I run loopback with no authentication, but I run relatively unimportant web applications that don't handle money, sensitive data, etc. Other applications may opt for B which is more secure. Using a loopback IP is pretty secure from direct attacks but if the attacker gets access to your OS via some other service or vulnerability, then the get full access to your DB which is game over.

Comment: I notice their is no L33T label for any of your summarised solutions. Is this a discreet comment on how nothing is ever secure? :| Thanks for your answer - there is not much competition here so I will accept.